# Text position in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react native I want to display some texts at some custom positions like in the following image:

[custom location react native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juFZ3.png)

How can I achieve this?

I've been playing with the following example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class TextInANest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titleText: "Bird's Nest",
      bodyText: 'This is not really a bird nest.'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.baseText}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText} onPress={this.onPressTitle}>
          {this.state.titleText}{'\n'}{'\n'}
        </Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={5}>
          {this.state.bodyText}
        </Text>
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseText: {
    fontFamily: 'Cochin',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

trying to set `titleText` position to `absolute` and adding some `top` and `left`values but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: React Native use FlexBox to position objects, you should read more about it there https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: You should use `flexbox` here are examples https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, we could say that :

- *Go to Jane's profile* takes 1/11 of the screen height, and is vertically centered
- *Bird's Nest* takes 5/11 of the screen height
- *This is not...* takes 5/11 of the screen height

As in React Native, the **main axis** is the **vertical** one (items are positionned below each others by default), you should use `justifyContent` to vertically centered a `Text` in a `View`.

So something like the follow should do the trick.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text>Go to Jane's profile</Text>
</View>
<View style={{ flex: 5, justifyContent: "center" }}>
    <Text>Bird's Nest</Text>
</View>
<View style={{ flex: 5 }}>
    <Text>This is not...</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved code with working live demo https://snack.expo.io/@akhtarvahid/demo

```
export default class TextInANest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titleText: "Bird's Nest",
      bodyText: 'This is not really a bird nest.'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.baseText}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText} onPress={this.onPressTitle}>
          {this.state.titleText}{'\n'}{'\n'}
        </Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={5} style={styles.bodyText}>
          {this.state.bodyText}
        </Text>
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseText: {
    fontFamily: 'Cochin',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  bodyText:{
    position:'absolute',
    left:10,
    top:'50%'
  }
});
```